# Kendo UI Grid resize textbox and Update/Cancel button during popup editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this kendo grid with popup editing here. How to setting `Update/Cancel` button and `textbox` size so it have a same size with `k-window?`

[Here I provide a demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ESibItas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Kendo how big the window is supposed to be, no need for some CSS or JavaScript: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.window

```
editable: {
  mode: "popup",
  window: {
    title: "My Custom Title",
    animation: false,
    width: "800px",
    height: "400px"
  }
},
```

Additionally, you have to set the width of the input elements to 100%. Make sure to put this declaration after you've loaded the CSS files from Kendo! Otherwise these changes will not be applied.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .k-edit-form-container {
    width: initial;
  }

  .k-edit-form-container input,
  .k-edit-form-container textarea,
  .k-edit-form-container .k-datepicker,
  .k-edit-form-container .k-timepicker,
  .k-edit-form-container .k-numerictextbox {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome. I'd appreciate if you'd mark my answer as useful as well. (:

Comment: any idea why it not center? Seem have a white space at left side. [DOJO DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/ESibItas/4)

Comment: The elements with the class `k-edit-label` have a width of 30% and the content is right aligned. The elements with the class `k-edit-field` have a width of 60%. You have to play around with the numbers until you like the result.